# how to change the value of button which is already in php

Tags: php

I want to change the value of the button.I have tried the following code

```
 echo '<input  type = "submit" value="<?php echo "button";?>">';

if(isset($_REQUEST['update'])) { 
     $e="SELECT * FROM procedure_1 "; 
     $e=mysql_query($e); 
     while($res=mysql_fetch_array($e)) { 
          echo "line 1".$res['heading']."line 2".$_REQUEST['detail']; 
          $btnName = "button"; 
          echo "HEADING".'<textarea name="d_ap" style="width: 100%">'.$res['heading'].'</textarea>'; 
          echo "DETAILS".'<textarea name="d_ap" style="width: 100%">'.$res['detail'].'</textarea>'; 
          echo '<input type="submit" value="' . $btnName . '">'; 
     } 
}
```

Comment: Why not just echo "<input type='submit' value='button'>";?

Comment: because it is necesssary for my project. Is it possible?

Comment: change it to what? plus, you're already in PHP so ditch the `<?php echo`

Comment: What's necessary? You're trying to echo a string into a string, when you can just handcode the string. It'd be different if button was a variable like $button - then you could use dots to concatenate the strings - ...value="'.$button.'"...

Answer (score 2):

Why not doing it directly?

```
echo '<input  type = "submit" value="BUTTON">';
```

You can also do this if you have variables for the name

```
$btnName = "button";
echo '<input  type = "submit" value="' . $btnName . '">';
```

Comment: I cant hardcode its value because the button is viewing through loop

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? If you can post the code that you mean, then, we might be able to help.

Comment: @Nathu I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but I think you're in for a very long haul. Good luck, I'm moving on.

Comment: Oh god. My eyes hurt.